# Regex for a range of numbers and one character for validation

Tags: c#, regex, validation, filter

I am trying to use Regex to validate a users input on a project I'm working on. The pattern I'm currently using is

```
^[1-9][0-3]?|[Q|q]$ //Range of 1-13 or Q|q (Can't include 0)
```

And according to Regex101.com it shows that a users input, say 15, is not a match, yet when I run the project it acts as if it is a match. How do I go about limiting this regex to only accept a range of numbers from 1-13 and the character Q or q? For context just in the event my while loop is wrong here is that code as well.

```
 while (!match.Success)
        {
            // Ommited Console.WriteLines to for clarity.
            FancyArtBottom();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(47, 19);
            userSelection = Console.ReadLine();
            match = Regex.Match(userSelection, @"^[1-9][0-3]?|[Q|q]$");
        }
```

Comment: Use `^(?:[1-9]|1[0-3]|[Qq])$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what exactly does the : do in regex? Can't seem to locate what it does. I've seen a few people using it before.

Comment: It's a non-capturing group.

Comment: See [What is a non-capturing group? What does (?:) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do), and this [2-min read](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/non-capturing-groups-in-regular-expressions/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^[1-9][0-3]?|[Q|q]$` pattern matches a digit from `1` to `9` followed with an optional digit from  `0` to `3` at the start of the string (with `^[1-9][0-3]?` part), or (`|`) a `Q`, `|` or `q` at the end of string (with `[Q|q]$` part). So, the `|` "split" the pattern and it matches more than you expect.

Also, [`[1-9][0-3]?`](https://regex101.com/r/PkWk3x/2) just matches more than numbers from `0` to `13` as you see.

Besides, the `|` inside a character class matches a literal `|` char, it loses its spcial meaning of the [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

You may use

```
^(?:[1-9]|1[0-3]|[Qq])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PkWk3x/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?:[1-9]|1[0-3]|[Qq])` - a grouping construct (a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)) (making `^` and `$` anchors apply to all the alternatives in the group) matching:

  - `[1-9]` - a digit from `1` to `9`
  - `|` - or
  - `1[0-3]`  - `1` and then a digit from `0` to `3`
  - `|` - or
  - `[Qq]`  - `q` or `Q`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
^(1[0-3]|[1-9]|Q|q)$
```

Or:

```
^(1[0-3]|[1-9Qq])$
```

See example: https://regex101.com/r/y6htBi/1

Comment: You are making the same mistake as the OP.

Comment: This would do the same thing as the post.

Comment: No, see demo, 15 is not matched.

Comment: Removed downvote, you originally didn't have the grouping in place. Now this will work.